# Solve least squares regression and force through 0 intercept in java

Tags: java, linear-algebra, algebra

I am trying to get the slope for the best first line:

```
SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression();
simpleRegression.addData(...);
...

simpleRegression.getSlope()
simpleRegression.getIntercept()
```

I am trying to get it to force through zero though so the formula can be reduced down to **y=mx**

How should I go about this?

Comment: I think this question might be useful for people who type in google: 

"finding least squares regression and force through 0 intercept in java"  as most questions w/ this problem are done via R.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the constructor takes a true/false argument for intercept.

For my use case of not having an intercept I would have to declare:
**new SimpleRegression(false)**